Aggregate progress in async context
I want to aggregate the progress of two operations in a sync function. The progress is being reported through a onProgress closure.
func doWork(onProgress: ((Progress?) -> Void)?) async throws -> Bool {
  let result = try await doOneWork(onProgress: onProgress)

  let newResult = try await doAnotherWork(result) // Progress not being kept track of.

  return newResult
}

I tried to create an NSProgress object and call becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount:) method, but it gives warning:

Progress for the current thread cannot be used in async contexts.


You would have to make an AsyncThrowingStream, completion handlers are not used with async/await
